# CDT-ASTRewrite creation exception

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to create a plugin to manipulate C source files using CDT, I am using  ASTRewrite object to modify the C files,Anyway it works correctly except for the following sample file:

```
#define CODE_SECTION ON

#if ( CODE_SECTION == ON )
/**
 * \Code Sample
 */
 struct
{
      int                  Var1[4];
      //Comment 1!!!
      int                   Var2[8];

} SampleStruct;
#endif /* End of Code Sample */
```

I get the following exception :

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.rewrite.commenthandler.ASTCommenter$PreprocessorRangeChecker.isCommentOnSameLine(ASTCommenter.java:86)

at the call of:

```
ASTRewrite.create(ast);
```

after some investigation I figured the removing the comment "//Comment 1"  or removing the pre-processing syntax  solves the issue , but I can't do this as I shouldn't modify the files I want to process outside the plug-in.
Does anyone have an explanation/solution for this?
Thanks in advance,